# What is an advantage of the Charles--Lauter--Goren hash function?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, collision-resistance, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

What is an advantage of [the Charles--Lauter--Goren hash function](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-007-9002-x) (based on isogenies of elliptic curves) among other provably secure collision-resistance hash functions ? I heard that it is slower.

Comment: None, really. It's just a building block for more complex isogeny based protocols.